# Google Spreadsheets IMPORTDATA imports "date" from CSV file as integer instead of "date"

Tags: csv, google-sheets, importdata

I have an URL to a CSV file which I would like to import to google spreadsheets. I am using IMPORTDATA function :

```
=IMPORTDATA(B21)
```

You can see the doc in here: [spreadsheed link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o8Hsw5mvYnMGar0U1Jvmos04Lty3iIkNFoQz11GPQp8/edit?usp=sharing)

My csv file looks like :

```
2023-06-14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2023-06-17,3,58,0,87,43,1,0,1,3,2,7,0,2,5,2,3,9,0,4,6,4,23,17
2023-06-24,7,185,0,263,123,6,1,1,8,7,16,1,7,16,7,5,15,2,7,8,7,80,31
...
```

The first column is a date. When the CSV is presented in the spreadsheet the dates from the first column are transformed into integer numbers:

```
45091
45094
45101
```

The whole file google spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

I have no clue how this numbers relate to the given dates, if I knew I could use some formula to recalculate them into proper dates. I have tried also to use query

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA( ), "Select * ")
```

But this did not solve my issue.
How to import the dates correctly as they are?

Comment: Select **Column_A** & try with `Format`>`Number`>`Date` selection

Comment: So simple and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of formatting you can also use another trick:

```
=text(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

I can recommend to insert a new column before your data (so use importdata formula from column B). In column A you use header "Clean Date" and use the formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(B2:B<>"", text(B2:B, "yyyy-mm-dd"), ""))
```

In this case the formula first checks if there is a value in the row of column B. If there is a value there it will perform the text formula. The arrayformula makes sure that this formula will be performed over the whole column so you don't have to add a formula in every row (makes your sheet faster and it will contain less errors).

Comment: you mean to add this formula to every cell of column A? or there is some trick to magically aply this formula to whole column A automatically?

Comment: If you add this formula in cell A2 it will automatically be executed over every row :) Just put it in A2 and you will find out (hopefully).